# Alert message box is not displaying when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to know whether at least on checkbox was checked, so I'm using the following code.

```
function CheckIfAtLeastOneBoxIsCheckedBeforeSavingForm() {
  var n = $('input[id*="ckHMreq"]:checked').length;
  alert(n);
}
```

When no checkbox is checked, the alert message box displays 0. However, when at least one checkbox is checked then the alert message box doesn't even display.

Any reason for that?

## EDIT

This is the HTML produced by the browser

```
<input id="contentMain_cklistPayroll_gvCKList_ckHMreq_0" type="checkbox" name="_ctl0:contentMain:cklistPayroll:gvCKList:_ctl2:ckHMreq" />
```

I also added "checked" to the jquery code. I still get 0 when no checkbox is checked and no message box when any checkbox is checked.

Comment: Please show the corresponding HTML

Comment: Can you post this as [a working](http://sscce.org/) fiddle, demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `:checked` to your selector, so that it only selects checked checkboxes:

```
function CheckIfAtLeastOneBoxIsCheckedBeforeSavingForm() {
    var n = $('input[id*="ckHMreq"]:checked').length;
    alert(n);
}
```

Comment: How would this explain what op *is* seeing?  e.g. why wouldn't op's code always alert the number of checkboxes (checked or not)?

Comment: @Madbreaks - No idea. Let's hear from them.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code always shows the number of checkbox inputs, not 0...

http://jsfiddle.net/hRubC/ (checked)
http://jsfiddle.net/szuzv/ (unchecked)

... so there may be flaw in your html.

As suggested in another answer, it does appear you will want to add `:checked` to your selector.

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/HFzJw/
At least in Chrome, your original selector works fine with the `input` markup you added to your question. Perhaps this is a browser-specific issue?

EDIT 2:
http://jsbin.com/iperin/1/edit (jsfiddle seems to be down this morning)

In response to your comment that you are getting the same with all browsers, here is another working example, matching exactly the markup you show in your question. Does this example not work correctly when you try it? If it does work correctly, please examine what else might be different elsewhere on your page.

Comment: I had :checked before and it was displaying 0. Then I removed it so that I was getting 10. Now I put it back, I'm getting again 0. However, when any checkbox is checked, the message box doesn't even display.

Comment: I'm getting the same with all the browser, i.e. once one of the checkboxes is checked then the message box doesn't pop up anymore.

Comment: Please see my second edit above. If the problem persists for you please create a working example so folks can reproduce the issue.

Comment: jsFiddle is down. Anyway, I just don't understand why it shouldn't work. I've bound some of the checkboxes so that they are already checked when they load. Still, when I click the button, nothing happen (unless I uncheck all the checkboxes).

Comment: Use JSbin if you like (as I in "EDIT 2" above), but if you can't reproduce it for us or tell us what is different in your rendered markup and code from what is in the working example provided, it is hard to help.